# CallygraphyXamarin not working in MvxAppCompatActivity

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I've have been trying for hours to get the custom fonts working in my MvvmCross project, specifically the Android platform.
I successfully installed the component and followed the steps mentioned:
https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/calligraphyxamarin

It just doesn't want to work.

I tested it on a activity than inherits from `Activity` and `AppCompatActivity` they both work correctly.
Seems like inheriting from `MvxAppCompatActivity` breaks it? Any solutions this this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Update

I released a nuget package for this (see: [MvvmCross.Calligraphy](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.Calligraphy/)).

- Sample project: https://github.com/smstuebe/mvvmcross-calligraphy.
- Blog post: http://smstuebe.de/2017/02/12/mvvmcross-calligraphy/

Just download it and modify your setup like:

```cs
public class Setup : MvxAndroidSetup
{
    protected override MvxAndroidBindingBuilder CreateBindingBuilder()
    {
        return new CalligraphyMvxAndroidBindingBuilder();
    }
}
```

---

Yes, because MvvmCross uses a custom layout inflator to bring in the bindings and some other magic stuff. This kicks out the Calligraphy inflator. Unfortunately, I didn't find a way usining the nuget package / xamarin component. You have to create a own binding and make `CalligraphyFactory` available.

**Modified metadata.xml**

```xml
<attr path="/api/package[@name='uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy']/class[@name='CalligraphyFactory']" 
      name="visibility">public</attr>
```

**Custom factory**

```cs
public class MyFactory : MvxAndroidViewFactory
{
    private CalligraphyFactory _factory;

    public MyFactory()
    {
        _factory = new Calligraphy.CalligraphyFactory(Resource.Attribute.fontPath);
    }

    public override View CreateView(View parent, string name, Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
    {
        var view = base.CreateView(parent, name, context, attrs);
        view = _factory.OnViewCreated(view, context, attrs);
        return view;
    }
}
```

**Custom binding builder**

```cs
class MyBindingBuilder : MvxAndroidBindingBuilder
{
    protected override IMvxAndroidViewFactory CreateAndroidViewFactory()
    {
        return new MyFactory();
    }
}
```

**Setup.cs**

```cs
public class Setup : MvxAndroidSetup
{
    protected override MvxAndroidBindingBuilder CreateBindingBuilder()
    {
        return new MyBindingBuilder();
    }
    // ...
}
```

**Activity**

You don't need `AttachBaseContext`. Unfortunately it seems not to work with `MvxAppCompatActivity`, but with `MvxActivity`. I'm not sure what causes this issue, yet.

```cs
public class FirstView : MvxActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        CalligraphyConfig.InitDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
           .SetDefaultFontPath("fonts/gtw.ttf")
           .SetFontAttrId(Resource.Attribute.fontPath)
           .DisablePrivateFactoryInjection()
           .Build());

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.FirstView);
    }
}
```

**View**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    local:MvxBind="Text Hello"
    />
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    local:MvxBind="Text Hello"
    fontPath="fonts/gtw.ttf"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Result**

[image: custom font]

Comment: Great thank you for your reply!! This will also work with styles? Have all buttons etc with the same font?

Comment: @cfl See my update on top of the answer. This solution works with `MvxActivity` and `MvxAppCompatActivity`.

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe It's not necessary using Calligraphy together with MvvmCross because you can create custom converter and apply binding to TextView typeface with font name. Look at my answer.

Comment: @MarekRzeźniczek Sorry, but with Calligraphy you can set a global font style even for elements that are not bindable / accessible via bindings. Nobody wants to write a binding just to set a font (I think).

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe If we need to set a global font for TextView we can create a theme with `android:textViewStyle` where we set the proper binding to typeface.
If nobody wants to write a binding for set a font, why you want use Calligraphy? Calligraphy override inflates process to change typeface, what exactly MvvmCross do and that's called one-time binding.

Answer (score 2):

Using Calligraphy and MvvmCross together is overkill because MvvmCross uses a custom layout inflator to bring in the bindings you can easily bind custom fonts to TextView typeface by a custom converter.

```
public class StringToFontConverter : MvxValueConverter<string, Typeface>
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, Typeface> Cache = new Dictionary<string, Typeface>();

    protected override Typeface Convert(string fontName, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        try {
            if (!fontName.StartsWith(@"fonts/")) fontName = @"fonts/" + fontName;
            if (!fontName.EndsWith(".ttf")) fontName += ".ttf";

            if (!Cache.ContainsKey(fontName))
                Cache[fontName] = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Application.Context.Assets, fontName);

            return Cache[fontName];
        } catch {
            return Typeface.Default;
        }
    }
}
```

And use it in layout:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    local:MvxBind="Typeface StringToFont('Roboto-Light')"/>
```

Or in styles:

```
<style name="CustomTextViewStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="MvxBind">"Typeface StringToFont('Roboto-Regular')"</item>
</style>
```

Calligraphy library does the same work, override layout inflate process and change TextView typeface, so it's undesirable to add next library and increase apk weight.